# Can I send a text message with Sinch without having the user okay the message visually? For example, through a gesture?

Tags: ios, sms, sinch

Can I send an text message with Sinch without having the user okay the message visually? For example, through a gesture?

I.E: Phone is locked, user knocks on their phone, sends a text message because of the knock to their parents saying "pick me up."

The part I need help understand is if we can have the knock send the text message.

Comment: If that could be done a milicious app could send costly text messages without the use knowing until the bill showed up. That would not be a good idea so Apple does not allow it.

Comment: Well, its not using the users SMS so not really. See my answer below.

Comment: If you ended up using the answer below, please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, the "problem" is that apple wont let you subscribe to Gesture recognizer in the background. While there is ways around this i.e looking at accelerometer data in the background I seriously doubt they would be very happy users since that would drain the battery since the app would keep the phone awake at all times and using the Accelerometer all the time

So its not really a questions if you can send SMS with Sinch in the background. Its if you can invoke code with gestures on iOS in the background. And the answer no.